# PHP copy image from url to folder

Tags: php

Why are my images not being copied from URL to local?
I get no errors or anything. I know there are a lot of similar questions - but I got no clue what is wrong. Feels like I have tried everything.

Hope one of you might be able to tell me what is wrong.

```
$url = 'https://example.com/media/'.$fetch['img'].'?w=128&h=128';
$img = '/images/hoses/fittings/'.$fetch['img'];

copy($url, $img);
```

- URL is valid
- Allow_url_fopen is set to true.
- Local folder exist and permission is set to 755

I have also tried using cUrl, same problem.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$fp = fopen($img, "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

What can cause this problem? Not sure where to look :(

**UPDATE:**
@04FS found the error. If was the starting slash.

Working code:

```
$url = "https://example.com/media/".$fetch['img']."?w=128&h=128";
$img = "images/hoses/fittings/".$fetch['img'];

if(!copy($url, $img)) {
    print_r(error_get_last());
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
```

Comment: result of `var_dump($fetch['img']);` please

Comment: 755 ? That will require the PHP user to own the folder because adding a file to a folder is a write operation on the folder (I think)

Comment: result of var_dump: string(9) "22334.jpg". The link is valid if I output it. Can load the image from url click.

Comment: Did you already check the comments in the manual? What is the return value of copy? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Have tried to set permissions to 777 (temporary). No change.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo Getting false return value. Copy failed. COPY ERROR: 2
copy(/images/hoses/fittings/22334.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: You are aware that `/` at the beginning of the path is referring to the server root, yes? (And not just a local path `images/hoses/fittings/` inside your project directory.)

Comment: @04FS That changed everything. I feel so stupid. You're correct. Post an answer so I can accept :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $img = '/images/hoses/fittings/'.$fetch['img'];

`/images/hoses/fittings/` would refer to the server file system *root directory*, because of the leading slash.

If you want this to be a *relative* path inside your project folder, then that leading slash needs to be removed.